# Port forwarding doesn't work on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, port-forwarding

I am using Huawei B683 router model, using this configuration as it shown below:

[image]

The static IP address of raspberry pi is `192.168.1.3` for both eth0 and wlan0.

**Update**:

here is the `ifconfig`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c5:ce:7c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:258833 (252.7 KiB)  TX bytes:2240090 (2.1 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:21957 (21.4 KiB)  TX bytes:21957 (21.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:90:9b:29  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe90:9b29/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1829069 (1.7 MiB)  TX bytes:415996 (406.2 KiB)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What kind of error message are you receiving?

Comment: `The static IP address of raspberry pi is 192.168.1.3 for both eth0, wlan0` - no it isn't, and it **can't** be the same - from your ifconfig, only wlan0 is 192.168.1.3, eth0 has **no** IPv4 or IPv6 address - if you want eth0 and wlan0 on the same IP address, you'll need to look at bridging those interfaces

Comment: How do I bridge these interfaces together?

Comment: Do they affect the port forwarding?

Comment: The IP address of eth0 is not shown here because the it's not connected with the Raspberry pi, it's configured on /etc/network/dhcpcd.conf